# Transaction not updating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to match two random players, and store their IDs in a separate table called Matches, but whenever I call the initialize_match method, only the time-stamp gets inserted into the record, and not the rest

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

# Associations
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

def initialize_match
    players = match_players
    with_lock do
  # Makes transaction
  user_1 = players[0].id
  user_2 = players[1].id
  finished = false
  save!
end    
end

def match_players
    users = User.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is user_1 and user_2? Are they attributes?

Comment: To assign values to attributes, you have to do `self.user_1 =` and `self.user_2 =`.

Comment: yes they're attributes of the Match table

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

def initialize_match
  fail 'cannot initialize unpersisted match' unless persisted?
  transaction do
    users << random_players
    self.finished = false
    save!
  end
end

def random_players
  User.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
end
```

I haven't tested this, so you might have to refine it.

I don't really see the use for `user_1` and `user_2` here since the association already holds this information.